# Can I create a dojox.data.XmlStore with a url pointing to a different port or server

Tags: dojo, xmlstore

In the following, I want to replace `/books.xml` with something like `http://server:port/books`. In essence the XmlStore to be served by some other server or port than the one serving this

```
<div dojoType="dojox.data.XmlStore" url="/books.xml" jsId="fileStore_book" rootItem="book"></div>
<div dojoType="dojox.grid.data.DojoData" jsId="model_fileStore_book" store="fileStore_book" query="{title:'*'}"></div>
<div
    id="fileGrid_book"
    dojoType="dojox.Grid"
    model="model_fileStore_book"
    rowsPerPage="10"
    style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"
>
    <script type="dojo/method">this.setStructure([{cells: [[{field: "isbn", name: "ISBN", width: 10}, {field: "author", name: "Author", width: 10}, {field: "title", name: "Title", width: 'auto'}]]}]);</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data store is bound by "the same origin" restrictions like all data sources in web applications. You should either proxy the other server using your server, or consider alternative means of data access, e.g., JSONP, or the window-name transport.